# Python3 symlink on linux mint

Tags: python, linux, sudo, symlink, linux-mint

I have been using linux mint for a while and have started coding in python recently. I once changed the symlink for python which by default was pointing to python2.7 in /usr/bin to python3.8. The system crashed on the next login. I ended up reinstalling the OS.

I then tried `update-alternatives` to link python to python3.8. It again crashed. I eventually just created an alias for it in ~/.bashrc. However, I just realized that sudo (root) does not source ~/.bashrc.

Is there a way to link the python command to python3.8 without the system crashing (linux mint)?

Comment: You don't want to mess with `/usr/bin`. If you want `python` to mean `python3` in your own interactive shell, a simple alias or function does that.

Comment: how about sudo? I created the alias within ~/.bashrc but that doesn't work when I do `sudo python setup.py install` Can I create a `pipenv` virtual environment and have point to it using sudo?

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to have a symlink in `$HOME/bin` and add that to the start of your `PATH`. I'm not familiar enough with `pipenv` to say off hand whether that could work too.

Comment: That should work! Thanks